# How to animate a mesh to make it resemble a waving flag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, vertices

I'm trying to animate a waving flag as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWirey_oNPY&t=7s, but I can't seem to do it correctly. An initial mesh has already been created : [image: this is the initial mesh that I am working with] My goal is to move each column of VerticeArray[,] (2D array containing the Vector3() of each vertices) in a sin function so that the mesh resembles a waving flag. GenerateVertices() transforms a 2D array to a 1D array, mg.nRows represents the number of rows that the mesh contains (in this case 5), and mg.Columns the number of columns that it contains (in this case 3). Your help is very appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class PlaneMeshDeformComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public float amplitude;

    [SerializeField] private bool activate;

    private Mesh m;
    private Vector3[] verticesCopy;

    private Vector3[,] verticeArray;

    private PlaneMeshGeneratorComponent mg;

    private float step = 0;

    private float previousStep = 0;
    
    

    private void Start()
    {

        mg = GetComponent<PlaneMeshGeneratorComponent>();
        
        m = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

        verticesCopy = m.vertices;

        for (int i = 0; i < verticesCopy.Length; ++i)
        {
           
            verticesCopy[i] += new Vector3(0, 0, amplitude * Mathf.Sin((float)(verticesCopy[i].x * (2*Math.PI/verticesCopy[^1].x))));
        }
        //4.
        m.vertices = verticesCopy;
        
        //5.
        m.RecalculateNormals();

        verticeArray = GenerateArray(m.vertices);

        /*for (int i = 0; i <= mg.nColumns; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k <= mg.nRows; k++)
            {
                Debug.Log(verticeArray[k,i]);
            }
        }*/
    }

    private void Update()
    { 
        step += Time.deltaTime;
        for (int i = 0; i <= mg.nColumns; i++)
       {
           for (int k = 0; k <= mg.nRows; k++)
           {
               verticeArray[k, i] = new Vector3(verticeArray[k,i].x, verticeArray[k,i].y, verticeArray[k,i].z+amplitude*(Mathf.Sin(step)-Mathf.Sin(previousStep)));
               m.vertices = mg.GenerateVertices(verticeArray);
               Debug.Log($"step is {step}, previous is {previousStep}");
           }
       }
       previousStep = step;
    }

    private Vector3[,] GenerateArray(Vector3[] verticesList)
    {
        Vector3[,] vArray= new Vector3[mg.nRows+1, mg.nColumns+1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= mg.nRows; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k <= mg.nColumns; k++)
            {
                vArray[i,k] = verticesList[i * (mg.nColumns+1) + k];
            }
        }

        return vArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized that GenerateArray() was not created correctly. I modified the post with the correction.

Comment: Your best bet would be to probably use a vertex shader instead. There are many more resources online to make a wave effect with a shader rather than in c#.

Comment: @MrDiamond I know that a lot of resources are available online to allow me to animate the flag but sadly I'm required to do it manually